# Omit day keyword argument from Django's date_based generic view?

Tags: python, django, django-generic-views

I don't want to have the day in the URL for a detail view while using Django's [dated_based generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#date-based-generic-views). I tried the following but get a `TypeError at /logbook/2013/january/testing/ object_detail() takes at least 6 arguments (7 given)`:

**models.py**

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return "/logbook/%s/%s/" % (self.pub_date.strftime("%Y/%B").lower(), self.slug)
```

**urls.py:**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from .models import Entry
from . import views

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^logbook/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>[A-Za-z]+)/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', 
    views.entry_detail),
)
```

**views.py:**

```
import functools
from django.views.generic import date_based

from .models import Entry

def prepare_arguments(view):
    @functools.wraps(view)
    def wrapped(request, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['allow_future'] = request.user.is_staff
        kwargs['queryset'] = Entry.objects.all() if request.user.is_staff 
        else Entry.objects.published()
        kwargs['date_field'] = 'pub_date'
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

@prepare_arguments
def entry_detail(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return date_based.object_detail(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Is it possible to modify the code above and continue to use the date_based generic view without the day in the URL? If not, can someone please give an example of a simple custom view for the URL pattern `url(r'^logbook/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>[A-Za-z]+)/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.entry_detail)`?

Comment: If you're trying to customise generic views, you might find it easier to move to class based views, in this case [`DateDetailView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-date-based/#datedetailview).

Comment: DateDetailView [still expects a day keyword argument](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17508). I think I'm going to have to write my own view.

Comment: I wasn't trying to suggest that `DateDetailView` would work out the box, just that it would be easier to customise because you can override individual methods. I would start with overriding `get_object()`, and seeing what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Alasdair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113962/alasdair) for pointing me in the right direction and to [ccbv.co.uk](http://ccbv.co.uk). I ended up using [DetailView](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.4/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/) and this worked:

**urls.py:**

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^logbook/(?P<year>\d+)/(?P<month>[-\w]+)/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$',
        DetailView.as_view(model=Entry),
        name="entry_detail"),
)
```

**views.py:**

```
# nothing needed here for the detail view to work, though in the future 
# I would like to have the generic view code here instead to accomplish 
# the same thing as `DetailView.as_view(model=Entry), name="entry_detail"` 
# in urls.py, and would appreciate an example of this.
```